# python multiprocessing.Process.Manager not producing consistent results?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I've written the following code to illustrate the problem I'm seeing. I'm trying to use a `Process.Manager.list()` to keep track of a list and increment random indices of that list.

Each time there are 100 processes spawned, and each process increments a random index of the list by 1. Therefore, one would expect the SUM of the resulting list to be the same each time, correct? I get something between 203 and 205.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
import random

class MyProc(Process):
    def __init__(self, A):
        Process.__init__(self)
        self.A = A

    def run(self):
        i = random.randint(0, len(self.A)-1)
        self.A[i] = self.A[i] + 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    procs = []
    M = Manager()
    a = M.list(range(15))
    print('A: {0}'.format(a))
    print('sum(A) = {0}'.format(sum(a)))

    for i in range(100):
        procs.append(MyProc(a))

    map(lambda x: x.start(), procs)
    map(lambda x: x.join(), procs)
    print('A: {0}'.format(a))
    print('sum(A) = {0}'.format(sum(a)))
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition

Comment: (You're not doing *any* sort of synchronization. This is a very fundamental, "skim a college textbook on process synchronisation before you even start coding" kind of issue.)

Comment: My impression was that multiprocessing.Manager() provided protection against race conditions (as you can see, it seems to mostly work, because my sum results ends up between 203 and 205 every time)

Comment: With synchronisation, there is no such thing as "seems to mostly work". With a race condition bug there's no such thing as expected buggy predictably buggy behaviour.

Comment: Also, where would you get that impression? It might be safe to perform any **single** operation on the list (e.g. an `append()`), but `self.A[i] = self.A[i] + 1` is obviously **two** operations, a `__getitem__` and a `__setitem__`. There's no way the list implementation could automatically ensure the atomicity of a sequence of operations that's implemented in your code.

Comment: okay I think you've answered my question then, it must be that there is a race condition between __getitem__ and __setitem__

Comment: please keep in mind that these things are not always obvious to newbies and self-taught programmers trying to learn! ;)

Comment: This is why self-taught programmers should buy textbooks or equivalent material covering at least the practical programming-related subjects of freshman and sophomore computer science college and read them; to make this sort of basic, foundational knowledge obvious to themselves. (I'm not trying to act superior here, I'm a terrible student and I've already flunked once; but from the classes I did pass, these are the topics that come up again and again and again in practice. What I'm trying to say is that self-taught or not you *have* to learn this stuff.)

Comment: ughhhh, also keep in mind that people-skills and communication are important in becoming a successful programmer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As **millimoose** points out, the problem here is a race condition occurring in `self.A[i] = self.A[i] + 1`. By the time `self.A[i] + 1` has been calculated, `self.A[i]` could have already been changed by another process.

A possible solution to your problem is to your problem is to pass the index back to the parent, which then performs the addition.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
import random

class MyProc(Process):
    def __init__(self, B, length):
        Process.__init__(self)
        self.B = B
        self.length = length

    def run(self):
        i = random.randint(0, self.length-1)
        self.B.append(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    procs = []
    M = Manager()
    a = range(15)
    b = M.list()
    print('A: {0}'.format(a))
    print('sum(A) = {0}'.format(sum(a)))

    for i in range(100):
        procs.append(MyProc(b, len(a)))

    map(lambda x: x.start(), procs)
    map(lambda x: x.join(), procs)

    for i in b:
        a[i] = a[i] + 1

    print('A: {0}'.format(a))
    print('sum(A) = {0}'.format(sum(a)))
```

Appending an element to an array is only one operation, thus the race condition is avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Answer came up through the comments above, there is a race condition happening because the following line:

```
self.A[i] = self.A[i] + 1
```

is in fact two operations, a `__getitem__` and a `__setitem__`